# R: For loop skipping rows with dynamic record selection

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm using the following loop to run an iterative ODBC query on chunks of 50,000 unique numbers taken in succession from a greater list of close to one million records. (Background: I need data from an ODBC source, but the source is too big to pull down, and I don't have write access to the DB. I know this is a hacky workaround, but I haven't found a way around it - bear with me.) "Key" below is the field I would join on to pull from the ODBC.

```
    for (i in 0:n) 
    {
    batch <- data.frame(key[(50000*i)+1:50000*(i+1),])
    *(other stuff)*
    }
```

I expected this to iterate on i to give me dynamic record ranges. I.e. for i=0, 1:50000; for i=1, 50001:100000. This works fine for the first iteration - where i=0 - but at higher values of i I noticed that the script is actually **skipping** individual rows, where the number of rows skipped is equal to i. So, where i=10, it'll start at row 500,000 of the base data set, but the second and third records will be rows 500,010 and 500,020 from the base set.

I'm sure this means that R is misreading some piece of my script, but I can't find the error (/I'm not experienced enough for it to jump out.)

Any thoughts? Alternatively, if there are other ways to go about this I'd love to hear them...

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think *you* misinterpreted R. ;) Try this instead:

```
((i * 50000) + 1):((i+1) * 50000)
```

with `i` ranging from 0 to `n`.